# python: child class cannot use parent variables

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a Parent class which holds some variables. Then I want to extend it to several child classes. Depending on the child, I want to group some of the parent variables in a list. However, I get an error

```
NameError: name 'VARIABLE' is not defined
```

This is the code I run, just to play around

```
class Parent(object):
    VARIABLE = 'parent variable'


class Child(Parent):
    list = [VARIABLE]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    child = Child()
    print(child.VARIABLE)
```

How do I do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

This code will work

```
class Parent(object):
    VARIABLE = 'parent variable'

class Child(Parent):
     mylist = [Parent.VARIABLE]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    child = Child()
    print(child.VARIABLE)
```

list is a reserved word of the language so you have to use some other name for your variable

Comment: yes, wasn't thinking about naming the list at the time. But just a question: isn't it a bit counter intuitive to have to specify the Parent class, since the Child class directly inherits the attribute?

Comment: No it is not, as Python support multiple parents.

Comment: *Instances* of the child class would inherit the attribute from the parent - but the problem code isn't in an instance: it's in the class body, which gets executed before the class itself exists.